# Problema viewport chrome movil - normalizador de css para vue 3?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Tengo un sitio en vue 3 para el que estoy trabajando en la version móvil, y me está dando bastantes dolores de cabeza. Principalmente ocurren en el navegador Chrome de móviles. Es como si este navegador interpretara el `viewport` de una forma distinta a los demás.

El contenido del sitio está dentro de una caja de `100vw x 100vh`, pero Chrome de android al iniciar, me tira parte del contenido del sitio hacia abajo. Cuando yo scrolleo un instante, la barra de direcciones desaparece y el sitio se ve perfecto.

En otros navegadores, la barra de direcciones se mantiene fija, pero el contenido del sitio entra a la perfección sin desbordamientos. Teniendo en cuenta que muchisima gente tiene este navegador móvil, me gustaría que la experiencia sea óptima desde el principio, y no que requiera de un scroll.

La pregunta en cuestión es, si existe algun `normalizador` o algo por análogo para
`vue`, o saben alguna forma de evitar esta diferencia entre chrome movil y otros dispositvos

Answer (score 0):

**Para futuras preguntas puedes apoyarlas con evidencia de codigo o de como se ve el error que se te esta presentando**

lo que puedes hacer es directamente validar desde javascript identificar el navegador y establecer que para ese navegador especifico el height de la caja debe ser el mismo que el del height del navegador